# Extracting a specific set of values out of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of teaching myself Javascript and I'm having a little trouble understanding something.

I'm trying to extract every one of the "Title" and "Instructor" values from this class registration page to make an enhanced scheduling tool for myself. However, in the examples I'm looking at, they all use the "getElementsByClassName(class)" and "getElementsById(id)" to extract specific information from an HTML table. When I look at the page source in chrome, I am not able to find either a unique class name or id to specify in these calls.

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction? Am I using the page source code correctly or is there a better way of doing things?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Here's the html of the page in question
view-source:https://admin.wwu.edu/pls/wwis/wwsktime.ListClass

Comment: Post your code in your question, not a picture of your code.

Comment: Can you paste the actual HTML vs a screen shot?

Comment: If this is your page, I would probably look into CSS too. It will certainly help with debugging html / js issues.

Comment: Just indent the code you wish to copy by 4 spaces, then copy and paste it into your question / answer.

Comment: @j08691 This is not my code, it is Chrome's "View page source" of the page I'm trying to extract data from

Comment: My point is that we need to see the code you're working with and what you've tried in your question.

Answer (score 1):

No you're not really doing anything wrong, but unfortunately the creators of the web page haven't made use of classes and ids in a way that will make them useful to you.

I'd recommend creating a Google Sheet to import the table. (See the importHTML function in Google sheets.) Then I'd retrieve the data as JSON and work with it that way. IMO you'll learn more valuable skills working with JSON than you will parsing HTML too. This article will take you through getting JSON out of your Google sheet: http://ctrlq.org/code/20004-google-spreadsheets-json

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I'll check that out right now

Comment: Hey mike, I just attempted this and I'm having an issue with the type of page I'm trying to import. [link](https://admin.wwu.edu/pls/wwis/wwsktime.SelClass) After selecting the search parameters it takes you to a results page, that results page is what I would need to input into the importHTML. However, that page is not static, so pasting the link results in an error page, as seen if you click my original post edit.  
Is there a way to do importHTML with these kind of pages? I really appreciate your help

Comment: There probably is, but it would basically amount to automating filling out the first page and submitting it, which is really beyond the scope of what can be covered here. You could save the HTML page that gets created elsewhere on the web, then reference it from there, but that doesn't seem to be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to use CSS selectors.

`document.querySelectorAll("tr>td:nth-child(3)")` and `document.querySelectorAll("tr>td:nth-child(8)")` will give you all `Title` and `Instructor` elements

Here's a jsfiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/n1fuo87p/